# How to allow users to select excel worksheet they wish to import into access using combo box?

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

I have created a userform to import a single excel worksheet to a specific excel table. However, the workbook that i need to import contains multiple worksheets which are the 31 days of the month on each sheet. Is there a way to create a combo box on the user form to allow the user to select the worksheet they wish to import into the access table using VBA?

Here is my code:

```
Private Sub btnBrowse_Click()
    Dim diag As Office.FileDialog
    Dim item As Variant

    Set diag = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
    diag.AllowMultiSelect = False
    diag.Title = "Please select an Excel Spreadsheet"
    diag.Filters.Clear
    diag.Filters.Add "Excel Spreadsheet", "*.xls, *.xlsx"
    If diag.Show Then
        For Each item In diag.SelectedItems
            Me.txtFileName = item
        Next
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub btnImportSpreadsheet_Click()
    Dim FSO As New FileSystemObject

    If Nz(Me.txtFileName, "") = "" Then
        MsgBox "Please select a file!"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    If FSO.FileExists(Nz(Me.txtFileName, "")) Then
        If MsgBox("Do you want to import this file?", vbYesNo) = vbYes Then
            DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12, "Dyeing", Me.txtFileName, True
            MsgBox "File Imported"
        Else
            MsgBox "Please select file again"
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Show us the VBA code you made so far.

Comment: Private Sub btnBrowse_Click()
    Dim diag As Office.FileDialog
    Dim item As Variant
 
      
    Set diag = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
    diag.AllowMultiSelect = False
    diag.Title = "Please select an Excel Spreadsheet"
    diag.Filters.Clear
    diag.Filters.Add "Excel Spreadsheet", "*.xls, *.xlsx"
    
    If diag.Show Then

    For Each item In diag.SelectedItems
            Me.txtFileName = item
    Next
    End If
   
End Sub

Comment: Private Sub btnImportSpreadsheet_Click()
    Dim FSO As New FileSystemObject
   
    
    If Nz(Me.txtFileName, "") = "" Then
        MsgBox "Please select a file!"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    If FSO.FileExists(Nz(Me.txtFileName, "")) Then
    
    If MsgBox("Do you want to import this file?", vbYesNo) = vbYes Then

    DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12, "Dyeing", Me.txtFileName, True
    MsgBox "File Imported"
    
    Else
        MsgBox "Please select file again"
    
    End If
    End If
    
   

    
End Sub

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When user selected xls file, you need to read the list of worksheet names as described, for instance, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18413048/5339178) and add those names to combobox: create a combobox with Row Source Type = `Value List` and add the list of names as string separated by coma to combobox `RowSource` property. In `AfterUpdate` combobox event import selected worksheet. Use Range parameter of TransferSpreadsheet function for worksheet selecting. Don't forget to add `!` to the end of worksheet name:

```
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12, "Dyeing", Me.txtFileName, True, strSelectedWorksheetName & "!"
```