# How to pick the right worksheet name when reading properties of an excel workbook

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

So i am using Opendateabase method in Ms Access to read the worksheet of a Excel workbook. Why do i get multiple entries for worksheets when I can only see one excel worksheet when i open the file.

So the system used to just import the excel workbook without checking the column names which meant after waiting 5-10mins of importing if the user didnt name his columns correctly the program would crash. I want this to check the column names before it imports which means VBA needs to know the name of the worksheet its importing.

```
Set db = OpenDatabase(Me.Text2.Value, True, False, "Excel 8.0")
For Each tbl In db.TableDefs
MsgBox tbl.Name 'Would be where the sheet name is picked
Next
db.Close

Set rstbl = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM ImportColumnNames")
S = "SELECT * FROM [Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;Database=" _
& Me.Text2 & "].[" & SheetName & "$] WHERE False;"
```

Now seeing as the file only has one worksheet called CLENAS i was expecting 1 answer however i got Sheet1$, CLENAS, CLENAS$ now i know it should be CLENAS but how do i make sure that VBA picks the right one.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer here: [Read Excel file sheet names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18412697/read-excel-file-sheet-names)

```
Dim objExc As Object ' late
Dim objWbk As Object ' late
Dim objWsh As Object ' late

'Set objExc = New Excel.Application ' early
Set objExc = CreateObject("Excel.Application") ' late
Set objWbk = objExc.Workbooks.Open(pWorkBook)
For Each objWsh In objWbk.Worksheets
    Debug.Print objWsh.Name
Next
Set objWsh = Nothing
objWbk.Close
Set objWbk = Nothing
objExc.Quit
Set objExc = Nothing
```